# table of contents title removed

Tags: table-of-contents, incompatibility, amsart, parskip

I wanted to change my paragraph style in my report so that there was no indentation. I used in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

Whilst this has dealt with the indentation, it appears to have created a new problem. I have included a table of contents and list of figures by using:

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
```

Previously they looked ok but after I added the `parskip` package the titles of my contents page have been removed. In fact they now appear below the contents page in normal 12 pt font. Has anyone got any suggestions about how I can change my paragraph style but keep the titles in my contents page.
This is gist of my project:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}        % only needed if you include TpX drawings
\usepackage{graphicx} % only needed if you include graphics files other than TpX
\usepackage{hyperref} % produces nice hyperlinks in your document
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\section{}
...
\appendix
...
\begin{thebibliography}
```

hope some of this helps.

**Edit** Just to include a screen shot of what the difference is. Here's the version without `parskip`

[image]

and here's the bad version with `parskip`

[image]

One sees that the formatting and placement of the `Contents` and `List of figures` labels are shot.

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick note on formalities: In this group, we tend not to thank people in advance with words for their answers. We're not being rude; it's just understood that the best way to thank people is to upvote useful answers and to accept the best answer. It's generally a good idea to wait a few hours after the first answer's been posted before accepting an answer; premature acceptance of answers may discourage some from posting their own (and possibly even better) answers...

Comment: With a simple document I don't get anything strange, so it's better if you try providing a minimal example. Frequently this helps in spotting the error.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the package interacting with `amsart` document class. As @egreg said, with `article` class there is no problem. In fact with the `amsart` class you see the following warning when loading `parskip`: `LaTeX Warning: Command \@starttoc  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.`

Answer (score 5):

The `parskip` package redefines `\@starttoc` in order not to apply a nonzero parskip to the table of contents and similar lists. However, the redefinition it performs is incompatible with the definition of `\@starttoc` in `amsart`. Load the `parskip` package as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\ams@starttoc\@starttoc
\makeatother
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\makeatletter
\let\@starttoc\ams@starttoc
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\makeatletter}{\makeatletter\parskip\z@}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This patches the `amsart` version of `\@starttoc` as desired. You'll still get the warning about `\@starttoc` having changed. Live with it.

**Personal opinion.** I wouldn't use `parskip` in any document longer than two pages. And surely not in a document using an AMS style.